# Symfony2 Fatal Error Class not found on AppKernel in Server

Tags: class, symfony

The project works in my local environment but when I deploy it on shared web server it doesn't work.

```
Server
 /home
   /app
   /src
      /gestor
        /UsuarioBundle
        ...   
   /vendors
   ....
 /public_html
   /web
   app.php
   ...
```

If I go to host/app.php ->
 Fatal error:
 Class 'Gestor\UsuarioBundle\UsuarioBundle' not found in /home/esdrhazc/app/AppKernel.php on line 19

AppKernel.php

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            new Gestor\UsuarioBundle\UsuarioBundle(),
            new Gestor\AdministracionBundle\AdministracionBundle(),
            new Gestor\ExpedientesBundle\ExpedientesBundle(),
            new Gestor\GestionBundle\GestionBundle(),
            new \Ideup\SimplePaginatorBundle\IdeupSimplePaginatorBundle(),
            new Gestor\MensajeBundle\MensajeBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle()
        );

        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
        }

        return $bundles;
    }

    public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $loader->load(__DIR__.'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
    }
}
```

Autoload.php

```
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;
use Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader;

/**
 * @var ClassLoader $loader
 */
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

$loader->add('Gestor', __DIR__.'/../src');

AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader(array($loader, 'loadClass'));

return $loader;
```

And finally, for instance, class Usuario.php

```
namespace Gestor\UsuarioBundle\Entity;

...

class Usuario implements AdvancedUserInterface {...}
```

I have deleted server/app/cache and give permissions.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: maybe you need to change the folder 'gestor' to 'Gestor'?

Comment: it seems to work. Now, I have other issue: Fatal error: Class 'PDO' not found in /home/esdrhazc/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/DriverManager.php on line 148 I will investigate. How can I vote you? To solve this I added extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so in php.ini

Comment: Glad it helped! I made it an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the folder 'gestor' to 'Gestor'